# Why is the "Domain users" group missing from this PowerShell AD query?

Tags: active-directory, powershell, groups

I ran the following PowerShell script to compare a list of groups....

```
$dasMem = Get-ADUser -Server "<some-srv>" -Identity "<some-usr>" -Properties MemberOf | Select MemberOf
$blahx = $dasMem.MemberOf | % { $_ -replace "^CN=", "" } | % { $_ -replace ",.*$", "" } | sort
$blahx
```

When I got the list, I ended up with a missing group, `Domain users` which I believe is a standard default group. Is there any reason why it's missing when I pull the script?

To be clear I was able to see the group in `Active Directory Users and Computers`, but not from my script above.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As silly as it sounds, it's because Domain Users is not actually in the `memberOf` attribute. You can verify in ADUC by turning on `View - Advanced Features`, going to the `Attributes` tab on your object and opening the `memberOf` attribute (not the "Member Of" tab).

The "Member Of" tab you see on an object's properties in ADUC is actually a conglomeration of the memberOf attribute *and* the primaryGroupID attribute. By default, users in AD get their Domain Users membership via this primaryGroupID attribute rather than an entry in memberOf. Though it's possible to change the primaryGroupID, most people don't.

Comment: Also, if you want a Powershell cmdlet that includes the Domain Users group (because, who knows), use the `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`